VS Code suddenly cannot connect in WSL (Windows 11)
I am currently using Remote Explorer to connect to my WSL in Ubuntu 20.04. Then, it suddenly threw an error, and I can't find a way to fix it. I have been debugging this for almost a day, but still no luck.
enter image description here
I have already tried:

-Shutting down WSL and restarting my PC.    -Uninstalling Ubuntu 20.04 and then reinstalling it.    -Uninstalling VS Code and then reinstalling it again.    -Deleting .vscode-server folder inside
/home/name/ directory

I have a hunch that I just need to change the VS Code configuration, but I don't know how to do it (I have already checked the settings).

I was experiencing the same error yesterday, but the following solution worked. I connected to my wsl with wsl command and then I typed rm -r ~/.vscode-server
And then I executed VSCode in WSL doing code ., which triggered a VSCode installation. This solved the problem.

Thank you for your suggestion, but I already tried it, and the error remains the same.
